# select a default value in dropdown list from two database tables

Tags: php, sql

I want to edit the employees's information in a dropdown list, I have two database tables where there is a shared field : in table1, I have many fields and one of them is the employee Position which is a number. in table2 I have two fields: EmpPos(which is equal to Position in table1) and PosName. Now, in the dropdown list, when I add a new employee I fill the list with PosName from table2 but store Position number in table1. the problem is in the edit form, I print all employee's info from table1 in the form to edit them but I don't know how to select employee's PosName from its associated Position in the dropdown list here is my code:

```
echo" <b>Position: </b>  <select name='Position' >";
$sql="SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.Position = table2.EmpPos";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $PosName=$row["PosName"];
    $Id=$row['EmpPos'];
    echo" <option name= '$PosName'  value='$PosName' ' . (($Id==$Position) ? 'selected'  : '') . '>$PosName</option>";
  }
}
```

Thank You!

Comment: Do you understand what you've written in `echo` line? `"`, `'`, `.` all mixed up.

Comment: I tried to add : <option name=<?php $PosName?> value= <?php $PosName?> <?php if($Id==$Position) echo "selected" ?>> <?php $PosName?> </option> but it select the right place but doesn't print any value in the dropdown list menu